# GVimと端末上のVimとではフォントの設定が別ですか？

Tags: vim, font

Vimでフォントを設定したいのですが, フォント設定はgVimに限った機能なのでしょうか.
それとも, 端末の設定がVimに反映されるのでしょうか.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CUI 版の Vim では、文字の描画は端末の仕事なので、端末側でフォントを設定する必要があります。
GUI 版の Vim(gVim) では、フォントの描画は Vim 自身が行います。`'guifont'` `'guifontwide'` (2倍幅の文字用のフォント) `'guifontset'`(X11 環境で有効) 等のオプションで設定できます。